# Key-Value Observing in Swift 4

Tags: swift, swift4, key-value-observing

I have the following code in my Swift 4 project.

```
class DishesTableViewController : UITableViewController {


    private var token :NSKeyValueObservation?

    @objc dynamic private(set) var dishes :[Dish] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // configure the observation
        token = self.observe(\.dishes) { object, change in

            // change is always nil
            print(object)
            print(change)
        }

        updateTableView()
    }
```

Whenever the dishes array is changed, the observation is triggered. But my question is how can I get the actual changes that happened, that is, how can I access the actual **Dish** object that triggered the change?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the reason `change` is coming up with `nil` is because you haven't specified options.

Rewrite as follows:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // configure the observation
    token = self.observe(\.dishes, options: [.new,.old]) { object, change in

        print(object)
        let set1 = Set(change.newArray!)
        let set2 = Set(change.oldArray!)

        let filter = Array(set1.subtract(set2))
        print(filter)

    }

    updateTableView()
}
```

Note that I have done a bit of guesswork here about your `Dish` object. I am assuming you have made it conform to the `Equatable` protocol, and this is a necessary step for the solution to work.

UPDATE: This requirement has now been reflected in the official Apple documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/cocoa_design_patterns/using_key-value_observing_in_swift).

> If you don't need to know how a property has changed, omit the options parameter. Omitting the options parameter forgoes storing the new and old property values, which causes the oldValue and newValue properties to be nil.

Comment: In my case, the `changeHandler` didn't even get called altogether because I hadn't included the `options` argument. I would suggest including it all the time.